# Can't run npm or any Node Module on Cmder (Windows 7)

Tags: node.js, gulp, cmder

I simply can't run "npm" or, for instance, "gulp" in my cmder. **But I can run it if I manually open the cmd**

```
λ gulp
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I run npm manually from the Nodejs directory, it works. So I added an alias with `alias npm=C:\Progra~1\nodejs\npm.cmd $*` and now npm works, but I guess that's not the best solution, since I can't run Node modules.

### What I've tried

- I've tried to add *"%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules"* and
  *"AppData\Roaming\npm"* to both System and User environment variables
- Restarting the computer
- Running cmd as admin inside of Cmder
- Add *"%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules"* and *"AppData\Roaming\npm"* to
  *"Cmder's user-startup.cmd"* path.

I can run Ruby's gem or Python inside of cmder just fine, but Node just won't work specifically inside of Cmder (but will work on window's native cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**

Download the lastest version of Cmder through the github repo https://github.com/cmderdev/ instead of downloading it from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "C:\Progra~1\nodejs\" to your **user path** in Windows using the System Properties window. Restart Cmder. Cmder can then see all the nodejs related executables, including npm.

The standard release from the website will work.

source: this has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmder as admin..

The reason why the workaround (moving files in the same directory) works is because running the cmder does not have privileges to access files outside of its directory. So either give it orivelages or Run as Admin. That it expands da the paths it can access and removes limitations/restrictions.

problem solved

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was using the cmder from selecting `save file` instead of `open with Windows Explorer (default)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Briefly:

Create shortcuts for npm.cmd and npx.cmd and put them to `../cmder/bin/` folder.

Detailed:

1. Install nodejs. For example, to `C:/Program Files/nodejs`
2. Install cmder. For example,  to `C:/cmder`
3. Go to nodejs folder and create shortcuts for `npm.cmd` and `npx.cmd` (right click - create shortcut). Windows will show message that cannot create here, will be created on Desktop instead - agree.
4. Copy shortcuts from Desktop to `/cmder/bin/`.
5. Rename them to `npm.cmd` and `npx.cmd` relatively (remove - Shortcut).
6. Reopen cmder, run `npm`.